# How should I adjust my monitor display timing parameters to achieve a horizontal offset?

Tags: linux, windows, display, parameters, timing

I have a 2560x1440 31.5" monitor that recently stopped displaying in the rightmost 4" of the display. This corresponds to ~320 pixels of dead space, so I am trying to create a custom 2240x1440 resolution that cuts that area out entirely from the display. But no matter how I configure the custom resolution, the display is always centered on the monitor, causing some of my screen to be displayed in the dead region.

I have tried using both the Intel Graphics Command Center and the [Custom Resolution Utility](https://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) to create a custom resolution by specifying the display timing parameters. Below are the default CVT standard parameters for 60 Hz that I used as my starting point:

|  | Horizontal | Vertical |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Front Porch | 160 | 3 |
| Back Porch | 400 | 40 |
| Sync Width | 240 | 10 |
| Active | 2240 | 1440 |
| Total | 3040 | 1493 |

According to [this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmzAa.png) I found in another thread, I should be able to achieve a horizontal offset to the left by adjusting the Horizontal Front Porch, Back Porch, and Sync Width Parameters, but no matter how I adjust them my display stays centered. Is Intel Graphics Driver automatically centering the screen and overriding my parameters, or am I simply not adjusting them correctly? And is there a way to achieve this on Linux that is not possible on Windows?

Comment: Your best bet might be to look at your monitor itself.  Most have some sort of setup options.  And some have alignment settings where you could offset the display.  But I doubt if you will get that many pixels.

Comment: Is your 2560x1440 31.5" monitor using an analog VGA video input? Everything about CVT and timings is specific to analog signals.

Comment: My monitor unfortunately does not have alignment settings in its OSD menu. And it is connected to a docking station through Displayport which is in turn connected to my computer via USB-C. I can try out VGA and DVI though.